# Routing in ReactJS. URL is displayed but component is not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have the following piece of code in my parent component:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}}
```

And this in Main component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <section className="section main">
            <div className="container">
            <div className="main-titles-container">
                <div className="main-titles">
                <div className="yellow-square"></div>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>
                    Introduction
                </p>
                <div className="button-container">
                    <Link to='/login' className="btn select bg-yellow" id="buyer">Next</Link>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          email: "",
          cellphone: ""
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
      const target = e.target;
      this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value
      });
    }


    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <section className="section">
            <div className="container center center-xy">
                <h1 className="title center-self">Title</h1>
                <h1 className="title center-self">Log in</h1>
                <div className="form-container">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue="" required/>
                    <label htmlFor="cellphone">Cell phone</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cellphone" id="cellphone" defaultValue="" onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                    <button className="bg-yellow center-self" type="submit">Ok</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Login;
```

On click I want to be redirected to Login page, but the problem is that when i click on that 'button' the URL is changed to '/login', but the corresponding component isn't rendered. However, if I refresh the page with that '/login' url the component is rendered. 
Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: I'm not using PureComponent and wrapping exports in withRouter doesn't solve my problem too.

Comment: Please check the duplicate. let me know if that doesn't work for you

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri none of those answers solved my problem

Comment: More code of the Main component would help in figuring out a solution then

Comment: please show your login and main component

Comment: @ShubkhamKhatri added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have the top-level component (in your case, `App`) rendering the `Router` component. All of the components under that (ex. `Main`) should not have a `Router` in the render function. They will inherit the parent's `Router`. You can still use `Link` or `Route` components inside of the child components and they will navigate the parent `Router`.